# Custom scope using Hilt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am using HILT library as dependency injection library. In my application user should login with username and password, and when success, I will provide the login token as a singleton to be injected to the rest of Activities. Till now everything is fine. But when user logs out and tries to login with another username and password, the token remains the same, since I've been using a singleton to provide the token. What I need here is to make a custom Scope, which will have the same instance for Activities except login Activity, But when user logs out and again login, A new instance of login token would be provided for the next Activities. How can I do that? Is there a simple way to add a scope living shorter than Application Scope, but living longer than other components (scopes) ?

Comment: Is there something that stops you from update the token in your singleton class?

Comment: if you are using builder pattern then can you rebuild you component when user logs in?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Hilt do not have support for custom scopes for now. It has few standard scopes such as ApplicationScope, Activity Scope. Alternatively, We can clear the token when user logs out of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Hilt does support custom scopes.

First if you want to scope something to completely new class, you've got to create a custom component as following:

```
@DefineComponent(parent = SingletonComponent::class)
interface MyCustomComponent
```

Then define a strategy of building the component as following:

```
@DefineComponent.Builder
interface MyCustomComponentBuilder {
  fun fooSeedData(@BindsInstance foo: Foo): MyCustomComponentBuilder
  fun build(): MyCustomComponent
}
```

Note that:

> While the @DefineComponent.Builder class can be nested within the @DefineComponent, it is usually better as a separate class. It may be separated into a different class as long as it is a transitive dependency of the @HiltAndroidApp application or @HiltAndroidTest test. Since the @DefineComponent class is referenced in many places via @InstallIn, it may be better to separate the builder so that dependencies in the builder do not become transitive dependencies of every module installed in the component.

And finally, you can inject it as you please:

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(MyCustomComponent::class)
interface MyCustomEntryPoint {
  fun getBar(): Bar
}

class CustomComponentManager @Inject constructor(
    componentBuilder: MyCustomComponentBuilder) {

  fun doSomething(foo: Foo) {
    val component = componentBuilder.fooSeedData(foo).build();
    val bar = EntryPoints.get(component, MyCustomEntryPoint::class.java).getBar()

    // Don't forget to hold on to the component instance if you need to!
  }
```

For more info see the official doc: https://dagger.dev/hilt/custom-components.html.